# extensions of holomorphic function on the upper half plane

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on the open upper half plane? Can $f$ be extended to the closed upper half plane, in general? Which holomorphic function can be extended to be holomorphic on the closed upper half plane?

I believe in general the answer is no, $1/z$ is holomorphic on the open but not on the closed UHP. **To extend $f$ to the real line, do we need $f$ to be real on the real line and why?** If that is what we need, then we can show that $f$ has to be a linear transformation with $\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ with $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$, but since we don't want to map a real number to $\infty$, so the map we need is $az+b$.

Comment: There's no hope. There are holomorphic functions on the UHP that "blow up" at every boundary point.

Comment: $z$ is holomorphic on UHP and closed UHP. There are hopes

Comment: Of course there are some holomorphic functions on the UHP that can be extended holomorphically. That's not all that interesting. And it has little to do with your question "Let f be a holomorphic function on the open upper half plane? Can f be extended to the closed upper half plane, in general?" - which is the question I addressed.

Comment: Yeah, I just to know the answer to the second part "Which holomorphic function can be extended to be holomorphic on the closed upper half plane?"